# How to get day of week from day of month in java (android)?

Tags: java, android, date, dayofweek, weekday

I would like to get **day of week** from **day of month**.

For example:

I have a date: 2014-09-10 13:45:20

I parse this and get the day of month which is 10.

Now i would like to know, that the 10. (tenth) day of the 9. month (September) in the year of 2014 is which day of the week?

Just like `Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);` which is returns 1 for Monday, 2 for Tuesday, 3 for Wednesday... etc

Comment: Confusing question. Are you trying to print, e.g. `Wednesday` for a given input date? Or do you want a method that takes `int year, int month, int day` and gives a string value of the day name?

Comment: I just want to know which day is it in the given input date.

Comment: That's not an adequate description. Please spell out clearly what your input is (including type) and what your expected output is.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 4):

Just call calendar.setTime(date); for your Calendar instance and Date object parsed from string:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
final Date date = dateFormat.parse("2014-09-10 13:45:20");
System.out.println(date);

final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(date);

System.out.println(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
System.out.println(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.WEDNESDAY);
```

Prints:

```
Wed Sep 10 13:45:20 MSK 2014
4
true
```

Comment: Its working fine but, Please Elaborate.... How the processing is done ?

Comment: @user5716019, sorry, what do you want me to clarify?